# Git: Is an unpushed commit just files in the index?

Tags: git, code-collaborator

This may be a misnomer in the tool I am using (Code Collaborator) but it gives the choice of adding "unpushed commits" or simply "commits."

I would have thought a pushed commit is a commit pushed to origin whereas an unpushed commit would have been files locally added and then committed. But it seems like unpushed commits might just be files added but not yet committed locally whereas commits are both added and committed locally but not pushed to origin. So is this a standard way to refer to state of files in Git?

Comment: As CoryKramer answered, unpushed commits are commits. But your question suggests that you misunderstand Git's "index" (which is not surprising, the index is a weird and arguably unnecessary construct; e.g., Mercurial doesn't have it, and yet Mercurial does the same things Git does). Think of Git's index as "the place you build the *next* commit" and you will be much closer. That is, Git has a thing that sits *between* the current commit and the work-tree, which Git calls "the index", that has a *third* copy of every file, between the HEAD copy and the work-tree copy.

Comment: It sure seems like, in Code Collaborator, commits are files that have been locally committed. I do not know what CC means by "unpushed commits."

Comment: I know nothing of Code Collaborator itself, but in Git, each commit retains an immutable snapshot of all files as of the state they had when you said "make this snapshot". (This snapshot is produced by saving what's in the index, forever.) Each commit also retains the ID of its parent commit. Chaining together all these commits (through their parent links) produces the history. Pushed vs unpushed just means whether you have sent the commits to another Git yet.

Answer (score 1):

Unpushed commits are commits (as in `git add` then `git commit`) that are on your local branch, but not `git push` to the remote.

Code collaborator will not upload changes that are staged or unstaged using this option, only committed.

When you select "Add Commits" you will enumerate all of the commits, by ID, that you want to include in the review.

When you select "Add Unpushed Commits" it will upload all commits that are on your local branch, but have not been pushed to the remote.

Comment: When I tried unpushed commits, nothing was listed although I had just added and committed several files; when I tried commits, I was able to add the id of the commit (which had not been pushed to Origin). Is it possible that I am misinterpreting or did something wrong or Code Collaborator can be configured so that commits means local commits?